# Magento 2 : How to create custom webapi?

Tags: magento2, webapi

How to implement web API in custom extension in magento2?

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to create `webapi.xml` under your custom module `Vendor\Module\etc\`

```
<route url="/V1/custom/:categoryId/products" method="GET">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface" method="getAssignedProducts" />
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

**– Route –** This is the URL which will be used to call our API

> https://{{MagentoBaseURL}}/index.php/rest/V1/custom/{{categoryId}}/products

**– Service Class –** This is the interface class of our API and the main method “getAssignedProducts” will be called with {{categoryId}} as the parameter

**– Resources-** This defines who has the permission to call this API. It could be anonymous (everyone) or self (customer) or specific admin user with specific permission for example Vendor_Module::custom which can be added in `acl.xml`

Lets now create the main interface file for your web API `CategoryLinkManagementInterface.php` under `Vendor\Module\Api\` as specified in `webapi.xml`.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;
 
/**
 * @api
 */
interface CategoryLinkManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * Get products assigned to a category
     *
     * @param int $categoryId
     * @return \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface[]
     */
    public function getAssignedProducts($categoryId);
}
```

In the above code, we have created an interface and define the main method i.e. `getAssignedProducts` as specified in `webapi.xml`. The other thing to notice here is the@return parameter which is the data interface \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface[]. Will explain what is data interface in our next step.

Based on the return parameter, let’s create our data interface `CategoryProductLinkInterface.php` under `\Vendor\Module\Api\Data\`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api\Data;
 
/**
 * @api
 */
interface CategoryProductLinkInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getSku();
 
    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSku($sku);
 
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getName();
 
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name);
 
    /**
     * @return float|null
     */
    public function getPrice();
 
    /**
     * @param float $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPrice($price);
 
    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getPosition();
 
    /**
     * @param int $position
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPosition($position);
 
    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCategoryDescription();
 
    /**
     * @param string $description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCategoryDescription($description);
}
```

The above data interface class allows you define the response/output of our API request, so as you can see this API will return sku, name, price, position and category description as an output.

Now your interface files are created, let’s create our model classes where we can put the actual business logic, to do so we would need to specify this in our `di.xml` file under `\Vendor\Module\etc\`

```
<config ...>
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryLinkManagement" />
    <preference for="Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface" type="Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryProductLink" />
</config>
```

In the above step, we have specified which model classes will be created against our interfaces to add our business logic.

Let’s create our first model class `CategoryLinkManagement.php` under Vendor\Module\Model\ as specified in `di.xml`

```
<?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
 
/**
 * Class CategoryLinkManagement
 */
class CategoryLinkManagement implements \Vendor\Module\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;
 
    /**
     * @var \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $productLinkFactory;
 
    /**
     * CategoryLinkManagement constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterfaceFactory $productLinkFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterfaceFactory $productLinkFactory
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->productLinkFactory = $productLinkFactory;
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAssignedProducts($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
        if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
            return [[
                'error' => true,
                'error_desc' => 'Category is disabled'
            ]];
        }
        $categoryDesc = $category->getDescription();
 
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $products */
        $products = $category->getProductCollection()
            ->addFieldToSelect('position')
            ->addFieldToSelect('name')
            ->addFieldToSelect('price');
 
        /** @var \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface[] $links */
        $links = [];
 
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
        foreach ($products->getItems() as $product) {
            /** @var \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface $link */
            $link = $this->productLinkFactory->create();
            $link->setSku($product->getSku())
                ->setName($product->getName())
                ->setPrice($product->getFinalPrice())
                ->setPosition($product->getData('cat_index_position'))
                ->setCategoryDescription($categoryDesc);
            $links[] = $link;
        }
 
        return $links;
    }
}
```

Lets now create our second model class `CategoryProductLink.php` under `Vendor\Module\Model\` as specified in `di.xml`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
 
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class CategoryProductLink extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject implements \Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CategoryProductLinkInterface
{
    /**#@+
     * Constant for confirmation status
     */
    const KEY_SKU                   = 'sku';
    const KEY_NAME                  = 'name';
    const KEY_PRICE                 = 'price';
    const KEY_CATEGORY_DESC         = 'category_description';
    const KEY_POSITION              = 'position';
    /**#@-*/
 
      /**
        * Initialize internal storage
        *
        * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory 
        $extensionFactory
        * @param AttributeValueFactory $attributeValueFactory
        * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory 
        $extensionFactory,
       \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory 
        $attributeValueFactory,
        $data = []
     ) {
          $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
          $this->attributeValueFactory = $attributeValueFactory;
          parent::__construct($extensionFactory,$attributeValueFactory);
        }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getSku()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::KEY_SKU);
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::KEY_NAME);
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::KEY_POSITION);
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::KEY_PRICE);
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getCategoryDescription()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::KEY_CATEGORY_DESC);
    }
 
    /**
     * @param string $sku
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSku($sku)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_SKU, $sku);
    }
 
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_NAME, $name);
    }
 
    /**
     * @param int $position
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_POSITION, $position);
    }
 
    /**
     * @param float $price
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_PRICE, $price);
    }
 
    /**
     * @param string $description
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCategoryDescription($description)
    {
        return $this->setData(self::KEY_CATEGORY_DESC, $description);
    }
 
}
```

**I hope this will help**

Comment: Only problem I found with the above code is that the ```Vendor\Module\Model\CategoryProductLink``` class must extend ```\Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractExtensibleObject```. Overall it worked like a charm.

Comment: @muhammad - thanks for amazing post. Scommerce\Custom is typo and it must be Vendor\Module.

Comment: thankyou so much @Vyacheslav to notice that class AbstractExtensibleObject override missing part. I have edited. also working for me now.

Comment: Thank you guys @VyacheslavShmal & Wakar, I glad it helped you & you liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it in 4 steps:

1. create a webapi.xml config under your extension etc
   `YourVendor\YourModule\ect\webapi.xml`

Its content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/yourvendor-yourmodule/testaction">
        <service class="YourVendor\YourModule\Api\TestActionManagementInterface" method="testaction"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

2. Adding an Interface that we configured above

```
// File: YourVendor\YourModule\Api\TestActionManagementInterface.php

<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Api;

interface TestActionManagementInterface
{

    /**
     * GET for testaction api
     * @param string $params
     * @return string
     */
    public function calculate($params);
}
```

3. Adding a model di configuraition in `YourVendor\YourModule\ect\di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="YourVendor\YourModule\Api\TestActionManagementInterface" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Model\TestActionManagement"/>
</config>
```

4. Creating a model class for implementing the API call

```
<?php

//Path: YourVendor/YourModule/Model/TestActionManagement.php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model;

class TestActionManagement implements \YourVendor\YourModule\Api\TestActionManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function testaction($param)
    {
        //TODO
        return $param * 0.1;
    }
}
```

After that you can redeploy your magento 2 instance

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

If you visit your magento store swagger (yoururl/swagger), you can see something similar as the image below:

[image: Magento 2 Swagger Output]

I made a detail tutorial on our devdocs, you can check detail here:

[Magento 2 Custom API Tutorial](https://www.beehexa.com/devdocs/creating-custom-web-api-in-magento-2-extension/)

You can see a sample output of the custom api we created on the tutorial.

[image: The Output of sample custom api call]

I hope this can save you ton of time.